# Javascript : Move to next element in a DIV using key

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Is it possible to move to next element in my DIV wih `E` and return to previous element with `A`. I'm trying to make a menu and navigate within only with keys.

```js
// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var header = document.getElementById("myDIV");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("btn1");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
  if (current.length > 0) { 
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```css
/* Mini menu CSS */

/* Style the buttons */
#myDIV{
margin-top:50px;
margin-left: 12px;
margin-right: px;
display:inline-flex;
}

#myDIV btn1{
top:3px;

}

#myDIV p{
top:4px;
/*margin-left: 10px;*/
letter-spacing: 1.8px;

}

.btn1 {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 3px 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    transition: 0.2s;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: visible;
    color: #000;
      font-family: Proxima Nova;
      font-weight: bold;
}
    
    .active {
    border-color: #366eaf;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;

}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV" style="display: inline-flex; margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 5px;">
  <p class="btn1 active">ALL</p>
  <p class="btn1">MENU1</p>
  <p class="btn1">MENU2</p>
  <p class="btn1">MENU3</p>
  <p class="btn1">MENU4</p>
  <p class="btn1">MENU5</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "move". A paragraph element is not a focusable element and so the user can't "move" between them. If you used a different element that is focusable, like a `button`, yes you'd just need to set up a `keydown` event handler on the document that tests for the keys in question and then calls the `.focus()` method on the desired element.

Comment: Thank for your reply. Well I have no problem switching to a "focusable" element like you said. If you can edit my code to show me I will be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semantically, you should be using an unordered list (`<ul>`) since you are actually making a list of menu items.

Next, it really isn't a "move" that you want, but a change of which element has the `active` class applied to it.

Your original JavaScript (while working) is more than you needed to be doing. See my reworked version with comments.

Lastly, you had some errors and some redundancy in your CSS.

See the comments inline for details.

```js
// Listen for key strokes on the document
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event){

    // Get the currently active element
    let activeElement = document.querySelector(".active");
    
    // Check for "e" and if there is a previous sibling
    if(event.key == "a" && activeElement.previousElementSibling){
      // Make the previous sibling (if any) element active
      deselectAll();
      activeElement.previousElementSibling.classList.add("active");  
      
    } else if(event.key == "e" && activeElement.nextElementSibling){
      // Make the next sibling element (if any) active
      deselectAll();
      activeElement.nextElementSibling.classList.add("active");
    }
});

// Just set up one event handler on the parent of all the menu items
// Any click within that parent will bubble up and be handled here
document.getElementById("menu").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  // event.target is the actual element that triggered the event
  if(event.target.classList.contains("btn1")){
    deselectAll();
    event.target.classList.add("active"); // Add active to the clicked item
  }
});

// Don't use .getElementsByClassName() - - it's outdated
let items = document.querySelectorAll(".btn1");

function deselectAll(){
  // Loop over all the menu items
  items.forEach(function(item){
    item.classList.remove("active"); // Remove the active class if its there
  });
}
```

```css
/* Mini menu CSS */

/* Style the buttons */
#menu{
  margin-top:50px;
  display: inline-flex; 
  margin-left: 15px; 
  margin-right: 5px;
  list-style-type:none;
}

.btn1 {
  top:3px;
  letter-spacing: 1.8px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 3px 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  transition: 0.2s;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: visible;
  color: #000;
  font-family: Proxima Nova;
  font-weight: bold;
  
  /* Give non-active items an invisible 2px border
     so that when they do become active the overall
     size of the element doesn't shift around. */
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
    
.active {
  border-color: #366eaf;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li class="btn1 active">ALL</li>
  <li class="btn1">MENU1</li>
  <li class="btn1">MENU2</li>
  <li class="btn1">MENU3</li>
  <li class="btn1">MENU4</li>
  <li class="btn1">MENU5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the details. Yours is different but have the same result, even added transition which I think make it smooth. While I'm at it, is it possible to make vertical transition between the elements ? Like the border actually moving to the next/previous element

Comment: @SeitoKimbo The direction isn't important. All we're really doing here is deciding which element should get the `active` class and that's the one that gets the border, so you can go in any direction you like.  Please consider marking this as "the" answer by clicking the check mark at the top left of the answer.

Comment: I kinda want the direction to the active element.

Comment: @SeitoKimbo Want the direction to be what?

Comment: when moving to next element > right, previous element > left.

Comment: @SeitoKimbo Ah, I see. I just had the `e` and `a` mixed up. I've corrected that.

Comment: @SeitoKimbo I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are asking. It seems to me that this is what the current code does.

Comment: I tried adding an `a href` for the menu, but so far the key binding only goes on the name and does access the link. How to make it so when you press E, you actually go to the link ?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense for the same controls to switch between links to also initiate a link as they navigate to it. Imagine you have the first link active and want to select the last one, you have to navigate through the ones in between to get to it, but you don't want to go to their destinations just because you happened to pass over them. You should have a different key (ENTER perhaps) that would cause navigation to the link of the selected menu item.

Comment: I forgot to note that all the navigation of my project is done on keyboard or gamepad, no mouse. So in the navigation you can't go to the last item without going on them. Kinda a gaming console interface.